# Ubuntu application to keep track of battery life

Tags: ubuntu, battery, battery-life

I'm running Ubuntu on my netbook, and I wanted a simple piece of software to keep track of how long the PC manages to stay on while on battery power. It could be something that automatically kicks in when I unplug the ṕower plug. But it could also be a simple command that I run manually to get similar results.

My objective is to find out how long my laptop's battery lasts.

Comment: Keep in mind that power use isn't constant, and will vary depending on how much you use the CPU, hard drive, monitor (turning off when idle and even brightness), etc.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm just trying to get a general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [acpi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/acpi.1.html) on terminal. Here's a [friendly tutorial](http://www.go2linux.org/laptop-battery-status-with-linux-console-command-acpi).

> check all the status together

```
acpi -V

Battery 1: discharging, 27%, 00:11:29 remaining
Thermal 1: ok, 50.0 degrees C
AC Adapter 1: off-line
```

Comment: ´acpi´ does not seem to be installed by default on Ubuntu (17.04). What is required?